# Setting data dynamically to Google Analytics Goals

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-analytics

I am working on an MVC application, I want to create dynamic goals in my clients Google Analytics and send them some data, so that I can get some custom reports in Google Analytics.
Can C# or Javascript or Jquery help me out.
Please suggest.

Comment: When you say 'dynamic' what changes? The URL or the value?

Comment: Would events probably do the job? Goals needs to be setup in GA interface and while there is some flexibility (regular expressions), events could be easier and also provide more detailed information.